# Calculation difference between a pre- and postimage in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am looking for a way to filter images from an ImageCollection 5 days before a specific date as Previous and 5 days after the specific date as Postimage. But it doesn't work. 
Background: due to an existing FIRM alarm the NBR before the event should be compared with the NBR after the event as dNBR. 
Here is my code:

```
function addNBR(image) {
// Compute the Normalized Difference Vegetation Index (NDVI).
var nir = image.select('B8A');
var swir = image.select('B12');
var nbr = nir.subtract(swir).divide(nir.add(swir)).rename('NBR');
return image.addBands(nbr)
}

var S2collection = Sentinel2.map(addNBR);
print('S2_Collection: ', S2collection );

// Create and print a histogram chart
var S2collection_NBR = S2collection.select('NBR')
.map(function(image) {
var date = ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start')).format("YYYY-MM-dd");
return image.set('date', ee.Date(date));
  })
  .map(function(image) {
  var ID = ee.String(image.get('system:index'));
  return image.set('ID', ID);
  })
  .map(function(image) {
  var date = ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start'));
  return image.set('date_time', date);
 });

print ('S2collection_NBR: ', S2collection_NBR);

// Create a list of start days
var dayOfYearList = ee.List.sequence(1, 365, 5)
print('dayOfYearList: ', dayOfYearList)

// Function to convert day to date
var dateFromDayOfYear = function(day) {
  var dateString = ee.String('2018').cat(ee.String(ee.Number(day).toInt()))
 return ee.Date.parse('YYYYD', dateString)
}
// Create a list of start dates
var startDateList = dayOfYearList.map(dateFromDayOfYear)
print ('startDateList: ', startDateList)

// Function to return an image consisting of count of valid pixels in the         date range
var checkDateRange = function(start) {
var end = ee.Date(start).advance(5, 'day')
var dateRangeFiltered = S2collection_NBR.filter(ee.Filter.date(start, end))
var pixelCount = dateRangeFiltered.reduce(ee.Reducer.count())
// return the image with a new property for start date, so we can retrieve   it   later
return pixelCount.set({start_date: start})
}
// rangesWithFires is the date for an alarm in the StudyArea
var reference = rangesWithFires.sort('date', false);

var time0 = reference.first().get('date');

var NBRimage = ee.List([
  // Rename the first band 'NBR'.
  ee.Image(0).set('date', time0).select([0], ['NBR'])
]);
print ('NBRimage: ', NBRimage);

var dNBRimage = ee.List([
// Rename the first band 'dNBR'.
ee.Image(0).set('date', time0).select([0], ['dNBR'])
]);
print ('dNBRimage ', dNBRimage); 

var pairwisediff= function(image){
var index = NBRlist.indexOf(image);
if (index !== 0) {
var previousimage=NBRlist.get(index.add(-1));
var diff = image.subtract(previousimage);
return diff;}
};

var S2_collection_dNBR = S2collection_NBR.map(pairwisediff);


print('S2_collection_dNBR= ', S2_collection_dNBR);
```